# Form validation plugin result in 404

Tags: plugin-development, form, 404

I'm new to craft development, and I'm on the verge of success in the creation of my plugin, but I have a strange problem.

It's supposed to save a record based on user input data. The problem is that it works on my computer, but not on my mobile phone (-> result in 404).

Here is the form

```
<form class="ui form" method="POST">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Activité</label>
             <select name="activity" class="ui fluid dropdown">
                 <option value="3">Third</option>
                 <option value="2">Second</option>
                 <option value="1">First</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="field">
             <label>Nom et prénom</label>
             <input name="nom" type="text">
         </div>

         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="eventEquipe/event/addParticipant">
         <button class="positive ui fluid button" type="submit">Je viens !</button>
</form>
```

Here is my controller's code
public function actionAddParticipant() {

```
$this->requirePostRequest();

    $participant        = new EventEquipe_ParticipantRecord();
    $request            = craft()->request;

    $participant->nom       = $request->getPost('nom');
    $participant->activity  = $request->getPost('activity');

    craft()->eventEquipe_event->saveParticipant($participant);
    $this->redirect('/agenda');
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, this redirects me to /login (I dont know why, I have no /login route) and thus result in a 404.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to [allow anonymous access to your controller action](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions).

I guess it works on your computer because you are logged in and thus have a valid session, but then when you try on mobile, you haven't got a valid session, your controller isn't set up to allow logged out users to post to it and therefore you get redirected to `/login`

To allow non logged in users access to this action, its simple. Add either one of these just at the top within your controller class.

```
// Will allow anonymous access to all actions within this controller
protected $allowAnonymous = true;

// Only allow access to specific actions
protected $allowAnonymous = array('action addParticipant');
```